# google maps ane: RuntimeException: Attempting to create multiple DataRequestDispatchers

Tags: android, apache-flex, google-maps, air-native-extension

I'm creating a native extension that shows a native Google Map from a Flex-based AIR application. You can watch lee brimelow's demo to get the idea: https://plus.google.com/110495278155587072613/posts/degSYVx8423

I got a working demo of a native extension, just to show an Activity with some buttons, but I got stuck when I tried to show the map. Here is the exception I'm getting on setContentView(layoutID):

```
    05-08 11:48:40.624: I/System.out(27917): WebViewActivity.onCreate failed with error:
    05-08 11:48:40.634: I/System.out(27917): "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment"
    05-08 11:48:40.644: W/dalvikvm(27917): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fd8468)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{air.GoogleMapsApp.debug/com.trasys.googlemaps.WebViewActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to create multiple DataRequestDispatchers
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to create multiple DataRequestDispatchers
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.ak.n.b(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.ak.n.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.ak.h.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.af.w.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.z.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.z.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.z.bw.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at maps.z.r.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e$4.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:809)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1037)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1019)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1804)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5069)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    05-08 11:48:40.654: E/AndroidRuntime(27917):    ... 11 more
```

I'm pretty convinced the communication between AIR and Android is ok, so I'm only posting my native code. (When I remove the map, the native extension works with no issues)

Here is the layout xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my FREFunction

```
public class GoogleMapsFunction implements FREFunction {

@Override
public FREObject call(FREContext ctx, FREObject[] passedArgs) {
    int layoutID, googleMapID;
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx.getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);

    layoutID = ctx.getResourceId("layout.activity_google_maps");
    googleMapID = ctx.getResourceId("id.map");

    i.putExtra("layoutID", layoutID);
    i.putExtra("googleMapID", googleMapID);

    ctx.getActivity().startActivity(i);
    return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my Activity

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            int layoutID = getIntent().getIntExtra("layoutID", -1);
            setContentView(layoutID);
            int googleMapID = getIntent().getIntExtra("googleMapID", -1);
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(googleMapID))
                    .getMap();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.printf("WebViewActivity.onCreate failed with error:\n\"%s\"\n",
                      e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "WebViewActivity.onCreate failed: " +
                   e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trasys.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.helloworld.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.helloworld.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.helloworld.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.helloworld.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
    Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="MyApiKey"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I see some com.google.android.gms. entries in the stacktrace, so I assume all google libraries are loaded correctly.

I created a separate pure native android application for testing purpose.
In this app I managed to create an activity which displays the map, this activity uses the same layout XML, the same google libraries and the same API key.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include third party classes on the jar file that is why fragment class is not found *"Error inflating class fragment"* .

After exporting your java files open the jar file with any zip tool like 7-zip, browse to com folder and copy the packages from third party jar file (opening it same way). After that you will need to recreate the ane file.